# Why does the accept() call uses an empty sockaddr structure?

Tags: c, unix, operating-system, unix-socket

I just got asked this question and couldn't answer it, I looked at how I've been coding it and was really confused.
This is how I have been programming the accept() call in a server:

```
struct sockaddr_in client;

size=sizeof(client);
if(( nds=accept(ds,(struct sockaddr*)&client,&size)) <0)
{
perror("accept");
close(ds);
exit(-1);
}
```

Where ds is socket descriptor

I know the second parameter of accept is a pointer to the struct but don't know why it should be empty.

Comment: It will be filled in by `accept`. It is _either a null pointer, or a pointer to a sockaddr structure where the address of the connecting socket shall be returned._

Answer (score 3):

Weel, it is an output parameter, you can send it or not, but when you send it, it will be filled with the the connecting socket.

Take a look here http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/accept.html

> If address is not a null pointer, the address of the peer for the
>   accepted connection shall be stored in the sockaddr structure pointed
>   to by address, and the length of this address shall be stored in the
>   object pointed to by address_len.

Comment: To elaborate, it's like making a phone call. If you make a call, you need to know the other party's phone number. To receive a call, you just pick up the phone.

Comment: And if you want to know the caller's phone number, you look at the caller ID. But you don't have to if you don't want to. Same with `accept()`. The output `sockaddr` is like the caller ID. And if you do use it, you don't have to use `getpeername()` separately to get it